# Does the Doppler effect disprove the constancy of $c$?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, doppler-effect

Why doesn't the [Doppler effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) disprove the relativity postulate that $c$ is constant relative to all sources or observers?

---

It seems it does because of the following example:

Suppose a ship of length $L$ faces an isotropic emitter (at the left in the diagram) emitting a constant frequency $\omega$ of wave crests a distance $\ell$ from the ship's stern:
[image: stationary ship]

Definitions:
$x_0 = 0, t_0$: emitter (origin)
$x_1$, $t_1$: stern
$x_2$, $t_2$: bow
$c$: speed of light (same constant in all frames)

## Case 1: ship at rest

### stern

$$|x_1-0|=c(t_1-t_0)$$$$x_1=\ell$$$$\implies\boxed{t_1=t_0+\ell/c}$$

### bow

$$|x_2-0|=c(t_2-t_0)$$$$x_2=\ell+L$$$$\implies\boxed{t_2=t_0+(\ell+L)/c}$$
Propagation time from bow to stern:$$\implies\boxed{t_2-t_1=L/c}$$

## Case 2: ship moving

(Note: Prime variables here do not mean another frame; all measurements are done in the ship's frame)
Ship moving at speed $v$ toward emitter:
[image: ship moving]

### stern

$$|x_1'-0|=c(t_1'-t_0')$$$$x_1'=\ell'-v(t_1'-t_0')$$$$\implies\boxed{t_1'=t_0'+\ell'/(c+v)}$$

### bow

$$|x_2'-0|=c(t_2'-t_0')$$$$x_2'=\ell'+L-v(t_2'-t_0')$$$$\implies\boxed{t_2'=t_0'+(\ell'+L)/(c+v)}$$
Propagation time from bow to stern:$$\implies\boxed{t_2'-t_1'=L/(c+v)}$$

Thus, **the bow and stern observers together measure different values for $c$** ($c$ in case 1 and $c+v$ in case 2). This contradicts the assumption that $c$ is constant.

The time difference$$\Delta t=(t_2-t_1)-(t_2'-t_1')=L/c-L/(c+v)\approx vL/c^2$$is still the same regardless if the clocks are biased or run at different rates. Even if time dilation came into play for the primed times, it would be a 2nd order effect in $v/c$. Thus, relativity of simultaneity or time dilation has no effect. Lorentz contraction, even if it made a difference in the observers' frame (the ship frame), is also a second-order effect: $$\Delta L\approx L(v/c)^2/2.$$ But the $\Delta t$ above is 1st order: $$\Delta t\propto (v/c)^1.$$

Comment: Why do you think that it would?

Comment: [No it doesn't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect). Why do you think it does?

Comment: Doppler effect changes frequencies, not speed.

Comment: The relativistic Doppler shift (linked in my previous comment) requires the Lorentz transformation, so it kinda depends on $c$ being an invariant quantity hence it cannot disprove the postulate of $c$'s invariance.

Comment: @Sean: See my added explanation.

Comment: Easy to confuse velocity with frequency. I think your question should be 'in what ways could c be varied for a given photon?'. Perhaps if a photon was near a black hole, we would see `c` alter for that case. You have some great answers which clarify here already though.

Comment: Good grief, all would be clear if you would draw a spacetime diagram.  I don't have the time or inclination to decipher your derivation but I suspect you haven't taken into account that the clocks at the bow and stern are *not* synchronized in the emitter frame of reference.  Again, this would be clear in a spacetime diagram.

Comment: How can you argue that "Thus, relativity of simultaneity or time dilation has no effect" when you only talked about time dilation in your analysis, not relativity of simultaneity? Relativity of simultaneity is in fact the key to seeing your mistake. Just remember that If we are using the frame of the source, then in this frame, at any given moment the clock at the bow shows a time that is ahead of the clock at the stern by v*L'/c^2, where L' is the length of the ship in its own rest frame. If L is the ship's length in the source frame, L' = L/sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2).

Comment: So if in the propagation time is L/(c+v) in the source frame, then if a clock at the stern reads T=0 when the wave hits it, in the source frame the clock at the bow already reads T=(vL)/(c^2 sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2)) at the same moment. After a time interval of L/(c+v) in the source frame, the clock at the bow only advances forward by (L sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2))/(c+v) in this interval due to time dilation. So the time it shows when the light hits it is the sum of its initial time when the light hit the stern + the time it ticks forward, or T = [(vL)/(c^2 sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2))] + [(L sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2))/(c+v)].

Comment: Do a little algebraic manipulation and you'll find this gives a time at the bow of T = L/(c sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2)). And remember that in the ship frame, its length is L' = L/sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2), so this shows that observers on the ship measure a time difference of (length of ship)/c between the light hitting the stern and the light hitting the bow, using their own clocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from your edit that you added the velocity of the ship and the speed of light classically. However, the velocity of the ship and the speed of light need to be added relativistically, using a Lorentz Transformation.

Here's a quick way to know something is amiss with your moving ship: You state that the stern observer sees a wave propagation speed of $c+v$ However, one consequence of Special Relativity is that information can not be transferred faster than the speed of light. Because $c+v>c$, you know something is up. If you apply a Lorentz Transformation you will observe a constant speed of light, $c$.

Comment: That's not the issue, since Geremia is analyzing everything from the perspective of the frame of the source. If the ship's length is L and its speed is v in this frame, then it is indeed true that in *this* frame, the time for the light to get from the stern to the bow is L/(c+v). The real issue is forgetting to take into account the relativity of simultaneity when calculating what clocks on board the ship will measure, see my series of comments about this.

Comment: _…it is indeed true that in this frame, the time for the light to get from the stern to the bow is L/(c+v)._ But it should be $c$ in all frames.

Comment: @Geremia - It is. (c+v) is not the speed of the light signal itself in *any* frame, rather it is the "closing speed" *between* the light signal and the bow of the ship, i.e. the rate that the distance between them is shrinking, as seen in the frame of the source of the light. In this frame the light itself is moving at c, the bow itself is moving at v, and so the distance between them shrinks at (c+v). And because of the relativity of simultaneity, the speed of this same light signal is c in the ship's rest frame--see my series of three comments in reply to your original question.

Comment: For more on the notion of the "closing speed" between two things in some frame, and how it is distinct from the individual speed of either one in that frame, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light#Closing_speeds

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments: The Doppler shift is a change in observed frequency due to relative speed difference. However, the speed with which the signal propagates is the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of a photon, and all massless particles, is essentially always $c = 299792458\space m/s$. The Doppler effect is entirely contingent on the fact that the velocity is the same throughout. We have a source, $S$, emitting light at a certain speed:
$$|\space\space\space\space\space|\space\space\space\space\space|S|\space\space\space\space\space|\space\space\space\space\space|$$
moving at velocity, $v$:
$$v\rightarrow\\|\space\space\space\space\space\space\space|\space\space\space\space|S|\space\space|\space|$$
Where $v=f\lambda$
$$z = \frac{\lambda_{\mathrm{obsv}} - \lambda_{\mathrm{emit}}}{\lambda_{\mathrm{emit}}}$$
Or, with respect to frequency:
$$z = \frac{f_{\mathrm{emit}} - f_{\mathrm{obsv}}}{f_{\mathrm{obsv}}}$$
At no point does the velocity change.

Comment: You're onto something good with the diagrams, but you should probably define $z$ and explain where the heck those formulae came from.

Comment: But you've got to show there is not a contradiction. How am I supposed to know whether your final equation implies a contradiction or not to your assumption $c=$const.?